# Difficult reccurence with two variables

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, big-o-notation

My question is a follow-up for the following thread: [Solving unusual recurrence with two variables](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129541/solving-unusual-recurrence-with-two-variables)

I baisically have the same reccurence relation but with a small change---

$$T(n,k) = T(n-1,k)+T(n-m,k+1)$$

**The change is the addition of $m$ in the second element in the recursion (instead of 1 in the original question)**

The boundary cases remain the same (for some given constant $C$):

For all $x \leq C$ and for any $k$: $T(x,k)=1$

For all $y \geq C$ and for any $n$: $T(n,y)=1$

I'm trying to approximate the value of $T(n,0)$ (with a tight upper bound as possible). In the original question we were able to give a close formula for the reccurence after $i$ steps, which helped bounding its value. But due to the addition of $m$, this formula doesn't hold anymore.

A direction for how to address such reccursions or any idea for the solution would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be less confusing to reparametrize $T$ by switching the order in which the second parameter increases:
$$
T(n,k) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n \leq C \text{ or } k = 0, \\
T(n-1,k) + T(n-m,k-1) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Having done this switch, let us get rid of $C$ completely. Including $C$ as the third parameter, notice that $T(n+C,k,C) = T(n+D,k,D)$, and so it suffices to solve the recurrence for some value of $C$. We choose $C = 1$.

Let us now unroll the recurrence. Suppose that $n > m$ and $k > 0$. Then
\begin{align}
T(n,k) &= T(n-m,k-1) + T(n-1,k) \\ &=
T(n-m,k-1) + T(n-m-1,k-1) + T(n-2,k) \\ &=
T(n-m,k-1) + \cdots + T(2-m,k-1) + T(1,k) \\ &=
T(n-m,k-1) + \cdots + T(2-m,k-1) + 1 \\ &=
T(n-m,k-1) + \cdots + T(2,k-1) + m + 1.
\end{align}
This gives us $T(n,1) = n-m-1+m+1 = n$ if $n > m$; you can check that the same formula works for all $n \geq 1$. Continuing,
$$
T(n,2) = T(n-m,1) + \cdots + T(2,1) + m + 1.
$$
If $n > m$ then we can compute exactly
$$
T(n,2) = (n-m) + \cdots + (2) + m + 1 = \frac{(n-m)(n-m+1)}{2} + m.
$$
When $1 \leq n \leq m$, you can check that $T(n,2) = n$.

At this point we can in principle continue and obtain exact formulas. However, they will be quite messy. Fortunately, when $m$ is constant, it is easy to prove by induction that $T(n,k) = \Theta(n^k)$; indeed, $T(n,k) = n^k/k! + O(n^{k-1})$. Obtaining an explicit dependence on $m$ is certainly possible, but unless it's expressly needed, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thanks! I just don't sure about the part where the equation is unrolled to $T(2-m,k-1)$, how did we get $2-m$ and what if it isn't defined?

Comment: Also, a dependency in $m$ would be very helpful, does it required to define the equation for $(n,k,m)$? If so, let's assume that the boundary case is $T(n,k,1) = 1$. 

To complicate this a little more, what if we also assume that $C=O(m)$ Is it still solvable with the same aaproach?

Comment: Look, you'll have to do some of it on your own. I showed you the way. You do the rest.

Comment: As for your first question, I tested it against an actual implementation, so it seems to work. Perhaps you could figure out why.